# Free RAM on my Nougat device

Tags: android, memory, ram

I am trying to understand how much free RAM i have on my Android 7.0 device.
When i open Android settings -> Memory -> there is "Free" value Average memory use of the last 3 hours (or another value i can select).
see following example image: [image: memrory usage]
but when i use 3rd party application from Google Play that show the free RAM i get totally another number (much higher than the number i see inside Android Settings).
I see inside Android Studio similar number to the one i see at the 3rd party application.
so what is the number i see inside Android settings?
Thanks

Comment: Seems not related to programming . try on https://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I see same number inside Android Studio as the one i see with the 3rd party apps found in Google Play. but i still don't understand what is the number i see inside Android settings. (i edit my original question as well). Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer options and go to settings > developer options > running services.
You can see real time ram usage in running services.

Comment: Tnx for your reply. inside developers options running services it show another number far far from the other two! e.g. inside Android settings memory page i see 50 mb free, inside Android Studio (or 3rd party apps i see around 300 mb free, and not inside developers options i see around 550 mb free!